# Every path $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^n$ of class $C^1$ is rectifiable, and the lenght $\mathcal {l}$$(f)= \int_{a}^{b} |f'(t)|dt$

Tags: real-analysis

Good evening everyone!
I am in trouble to demonstrate the folowing theorem:

"Every path $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^n$ of class $C^1$ is rectifiable, and the length $\mathcal {l}$$(f)= \int_{a}^{b} |f'(t)|dt$".

I want to show that $\lim_{|P|\rightarrow 0}\mathcal l$$(f,P)= \int_{a}^{b} |f'(t)|dt$. So, given $\varepsilon >0$, I take a partition $P=\{t_0,t_1,...,t_k\}$ and a point $\phi_i=t_{i-1} \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$. Then there exists $\delta_1 >0$ such that $|P|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow \left|\int_{a}^{b} |f'(t)|dt-\sum_{i=1}^k |f'(t_{i-1})|(t_i-t_{i-1}) \right|< \varepsilon$.
I must get a result like $|P|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow \left|\mathcal{l}(f,P)-\int_{a}^{b} |f'(t)| dt \right| < \varepsilon$, but how?

Comment: If it is $C^1$ then it is Lipschitz, so you can show that it is rectifiable from this.

Comment: The mean value theorem shows that $|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})| = |f'(\xi_i)| (t_i -t_{i-1})$ for some $\xi_i \in (t_i, t_{i-1})$.

Comment: This has been dealt with before several times. See, e.g., the answer to this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556805/question-on-riemann-sums/865993#865993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P=(t_0=a,....,t_n=b)$ is a partition, let $l_P(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f(t_{k+1})-f(t_k)|$.
We have $l_P(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} | \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} f'(t) dt | \le
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} |f'(t)| dt = \int |f'|$, from which it follows that $f$ is rectifiable.

Now let $g_P = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \inf_{ [t_k,t_{k+1})} |f'(t)| 1_{ [t_k,t_{k+1}) } $. We have $g_P(t) \le |f'(t)|$ and since $f$ is $C^1$, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a partition such that $|f'(t)| -g_P(t) < \epsilon {1 \over b-a}$. Hence we have $\int g_P \le \int |f'| \le \int g_P + \epsilon$.

Using the mean value theorem, we have 
$l_P(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f'(\xi_k)| (t_{k+1}-t_k)$, for some $\xi_k \in [t_k,t_{k+1})$, and hence $\int g_P \le l_P(f)$.

Combining the above, we have $\int g_P \le l_P(f) \le \int |f'| \le \int g_P + \epsilon$. It follows that $\sup_P l_P(f) = \int |f'|$,
where the $\sup$ is taken over all partitions of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Hello, Copper! You wrote: Using the mean value theorem, we have $l_P(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f'(\xi_k)| (t_{k+1}-t_k)$". Why is it not enough to ptove that $\sup_P l_P(f) = \int |f'|$?

Comment: @Walterr: I not sure I understand your question. That is what I am trying to do?

Comment: Copper, if $f$ is $C^1$ then $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is continuous in every interval $[t_{k},t_{k+1}]$. By Mean value Theorem, in every such interval there exists $\xi_i$ such that $f(t_{k+1})-f(t_k)=f'(\xi_i)(t_{k+1}-t_k) \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^n |f(t_{k+1}-f(t_k)|= \sum_{k=0}^n |f'(\xi_i)|(t_{k+1}-t_k)$. On the other hanf, $|P|\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow n \rightarrow \infty$. In my opinion, this argumentation is enough  to prove that $\mathcal {l}(f)= \int|f'|$.

Comment: @Walterr: You could argue that way.